# SQL Query to get the first day of the month passed in the parameter of the current year

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the first day and last day of the month passed in the parameter.

I tried to use the below query, but it is erroring out.

```
select LAST_DAY(to_date(to_char(('01'||:P_MONTH||'2020'),'DDMMYYYY'),'YYYYMM'))
FROM DUAL
```

I want to use this in a query

```
select * from
GL_CODE_TAB
where effective_start_date = LAST_DAY(to_date(to_char(('01'||:P_MONTH||'2020'),'DDMMYYYY'),'YYYYMMDD'))
```

and search the table GL_CODE_TAB for the first/last day of the month I pass, e.g. if I pass "May"

```
select * from
GL_CODE_TAB
where effective_start_date = LAST_DAY(to_date(to_char(('01'||'May'||'2020'),'DDMMYYYY'),'YYYYMMDD'))
```

which should do a search like

```
 select * from
    GL_CODE_TAB
    where effective_start_date = '20200531'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi, Ive edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is off in your logic.  You don't need to convert strings to strings.  So, I am thinking:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01' || :P_MONTH || '2020', 'DDMMYYYY'))
FROM DUAL
```

The pattern `MM` is looking for a *numerical* month.  (You also have the format pattern `'DDMMYYYY'` twice in your query; I am not sure why.)

It so happens that that Oracle defaults the year to the current year and the day of the month to the current month.  So, you don't even need to mess around with strings:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(:P_MONTH , 'MM'))
FROM DUAL;
```

The above assumes a *numerical* value for your parameter.  If you want to handle a string, then:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01' || :P_MONTH || '2020', 'DDMONYYYY'))
FROM DUAL
```

Or:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(:P_MONTH , 'MON'))
FROM DUAL;
```

If you want to pass the full month name, use `MONTH` instead of `MON`.

Comment: Oh i did not know the last solution.. Thanks !

Comment: i am getting an error ORA-01843: not a valid month when i use LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(:P_MONTH , 'MON'))

Answer (score 0):

The inner call to `TO_CHAR()` is the problem. Just use `TO_DATE()` as follows, with the proper format specifier as second argument:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01 ' || :P_MONTH || ' 2020'),'DD MONTH YYYY'))
FROM DUAL
```

It is unclear whether the parameter is a full or abbreviated month name (May is ambiguous in that regard). I assumed it's the former. If that's a short name, then use `'DD MON YYYY'` instead.

In your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM GL_CODE_TAB
WHERE effective_start_date = LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01 ' || :P_MONTH || ' 2020'),'DD MONTH YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `20200531` in the where clause, I think you want

```
select to_char(last_day(to_date(('01'||'May'||'2020'),'DDMMYYYY')), 'YYYYMMDD')
from dual;
```